# SqlConnection.InfoMessage Stops Firing

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When I have my EF model mapping for a stored procedure set to a complex type I'm losing messages output by the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[TestPrints]
AS
    PRINT 'hello world 1'

    SELECT 1 AS 'Test Column'

    PRINT 'hello world 2'
RETURN 0

var res = new Entities();
var sqlConn = (SqlConnection)res.Database.Connection;
sqlConn.InfoMessage += (obj, e) => { msgs.Add(e.Message); };
```

When the stored procedure is mapped to a complex type, `msgs` contains 1 entry:

```
'hello world 1'
```

When the stored procedure is not mapped to a complex type, `msgs` contains 2 entries:

```
'hello world 1' 
'hello world 2'
```

[image: screenshot of EF mapping]

[Sample Code](https://github.com/spottedmahn/DebugSqlConnectionInfoMessage)